# SkiaSharp XPS document creation failing on Linux

Tags: skiasharp

I can create an XPS file with SkiaSharp fine like this on Windows:

```
_outputStream = File.Create(outputFileName);
_managedStream = new SKManagedWStream(_outputStream);

if(_outputStream == null || _managedStream == null)
{
  throw new System.Exception("XPS Streams not created");
}

Logger.LogInformation("Creating XPS document");
Document = SKDocument.CreateXps(_managedStream);

if(Document == null)
{
  throw new System.Exception("Could not create XPS Document");
}
```

But on Linux (AWS container linux) it silently fails - ie, Document is null and it throws my null check exception.

Documentation is almost non existent as are blog posts for anything SkiaSharp.  Has anyone here got this to work well?

Answer (score 0):

Only supported on windows apparently.  Another reason Im starting to dislike SkiaSharp.

https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/fc9f030a08eb158fb934774cdf54f8df939088c7/tests/Tests/SKDocumentTest.cs#L136